# How do I print out a simple array with numbers 0-99 on the console

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to CS and I'm stuck on a practice problem in arrays where I have to print out an array with numbers 0-99 onto the console. My code right now seems to just create the numbers and print them but not actually put them in the array. I'm just curious how to actually set the elements to the array and then print them because that's the only thing holding me back from finishing the rest of the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int num[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        num[i] = 0;
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your array is filled only with 0s. Also you are printing the address of (the first element of) the array, not its contents

Comment: There is no mechanism for printing array content to an std::ostream. You can iterate over your array and print the value in each position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are very close! You just need to assign the value of 'i' into your array slot. Hope this helps!

EDIT:
To print the contents of the array you need to iterate back over the array and print each array element.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int num[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        num[i] = i;  //assign value of 'i' to array slot

    //print array elements
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        cout << num[i]<< endl;

}
```

Comment: when I do that I end up just getting this  003DF628 printed on the console

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry about that bud.

Answer (score 0):

read the correct carefully:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>     // its C++ equivalent
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int num[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        num[i] = i;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        cout << "num[" << i << "]" << num[i] << endl;
}
```